# c++, send data to output file

Tags: c++, database

I have created a small system for assignment. Kindly can anyone guide me how to send the data to output file/database file. I need to save the records and later edit and delete as needed. Therefore I need to send data to some database file. Kindly help

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <dos.h>
using namespace std;
string userName;
string passWord;
string selection;
int option;

struct patientinfo {
    string PatientFname;
    string PatientLname;
    int Age;
    int ContactNo;
    string TreatmentType;
    string AppDate;
    string AppTime;
    int eReciptId;
};

int num;
patientinfo emp[50];
ofstream outputFile("ST.txt");

int main()
{

int i=num;
num+=1;

cout<< endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl 
<< setw(65)<<"|Booking|"  << endl  << endl  << endl  << endl
<< setw(30)<<"First Name       : ";
cin>>emp[i].PatientFname;
cout<< setw(30)<<"Last Name        : ";
cin>>emp[i].PatientLname;
cout<< setw(30)<<"Age              : ";
cin>>emp[i].Age;
cout<< setw(30)<<"Contact No       : ";
cin>>emp[i].ContactNo;
cout<< setw(30)<<"Appointment Date : " ;
cin>>emp[i].AppDate;
cout<< setw(30)<<"Appointment Time : ";
cin>>emp[i].AppTime;
};
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: tried to send outputFile as ofstream. didnt work.

Comment: `num` is uninitialized, therefore `i` has indeterminate value. UB. You should be getting an error/warning.

Comment: @ceranda And you mistyped `for`-loop with what I said above.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what the requirements/exclusions for the assignment are. For something like this, I'd always use the fairly light-weight option of sqlite. It's used everywhere, it's stable, it's free, it's a database engine capable of accepting SQL statements. It makes later retrieval and modifications of records a breeze. If it's not formally disallowed, I'd use it in a heart-beat.

Answer (score 0):

guess you have to use a specific format when writhing so you can be able to read it back . Probably commas between every patient. For example

```
      if (outputFile.is_open())
      {
          for(int x=0; x<50; i++
          {
            outputFile << emp[i].PatientFname << "," <<emp[i].PatientLname << "," << emp[i].Age <<"\n";
    }
        outputFile.close();
      }
```

then you can open it with ifstream. Each line with be a patient and then the comma separation can give you each's patients properties